# Using Contains() to check multiple object values exist in list before adding new list?

Tags: c#

How do I check for multiple properties in object to see if it exists in list before adding new object to list?   The Contains() doesn't work here, so what should work instead?

What I have here is a large list model and I want to port some data over to a new shorter list model having no duplication values, having unique values.

Thanks..

```
public class Fee {
   public string Year { get; set; }
   public string Make { get; set; }
   public string Model { get; set; }
   public string Vin { get; set; }
   public string Color { get; set; }
}
public class Foo {
   public string Year { get; set; }
   public string Make { get; set; }
   public string Model { get; set; }
}

List<Fee> modelVehicles = new List<Fee>();
List<Foo> returnVehicles = new List<Foo>();

modelVehicles.Add(new Fee() { Year = "2001", Make = "Ford", Model = "Mustang", Vin = "111", Color = "Green" });
modelVehicles.Add(new Fee() { Year = "2001", Make = "Ford", Model = "Mustang", Vin = "222", Color = "Red" });
modelVehicles.Add(new Fee() { Year = "2001", Make = "Ford", Model = "Mustang", Vin = "333", Color = "Black" });

foreach(var v in modelVehicles)
{
    if (returnVehicles.Contains(new Foo { Year = v.Year, Make = v.Make, Model = v.Model }) == false)
    {
       returnVehicles.Add(
           new Foo {
               Year = v.Year,
               Make = v.Make, 
               Model = v.Model
           }
       );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` operator, because in fact your operation is grouping:

```
returnVehicles = modelVehicles.GroupBy(x => new { x.Year, x.Make, x.Model }, 
                                       x => new Foo() {
                                           Year = x.Year,
                                           Make = x.Make,
                                           Model = x.Model
                                      },
                                      (key, values) => values.First())
                               .ToList();
```

And if you implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for `Foo`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Foo other = obj as Foo;
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        return string.Equals(Year, other.Year) && 
               string.Equals(Make, other.Make) && 
               string.Equals(Model, other.Model);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 13;
        hash = (hash * 7) + Year.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 7) + Make.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 7) + Model.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

this can be simplified:

```
returnVehicles = modelVehicles.GroupBy(x => new Foo() {
                                               Year = x.Year,
                                               Make = x.Make,
                                               Model = x.Model
                                            }, 
                                       (key, values) => key)
                                .ToList();
```

Comment: I think you mean `new { x.Year, x.Make , x.Model } `

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is get a list of the distinct items, then use [Enumerable.Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338049(v=vs.100).aspx). You just have to create an [equality comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
class VehicleEqualityComparer: EqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    public override int GetHashCode(Foo f)
    {
        // A reasonably decent hash code for this application.
        return (f.Make.GetHashCode() << 16)
               | (f.Model.GetHashCode() >> 16)
               ^ f.Year;
    }

    public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null) return true;
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        return x.Year == y.Year
            && x.Make == y.Make
            && x.Model == y.Model;
    }
}
```

And to get a list of distinct items:

```
var returnVehicles = modelVehicles.Distinct(new VehicleEqualityComparer()).ToList();
```